# How to preload images during a looped array for background images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a simple loop that cycles through a series of images in an array into the background-image property of an element. The problem is that due to the fact that the images are loading, the animation is going haywire when everything is initially loading. I'm trying to set up a preloading workflow where:

1. the entire loop is blocked by waiting until the first image is fully loaded
2. every time a new image is fully preloaded, it begins preloading the following image
3. the preloading must stop when the array is over and use cached images so it's easy on the browser and doesnt just keep loading the same array on images over and over eternally.

Any help?

http://codepen.io/jeremypbeasley/pen/JoZzyo?editors=001

```
var photoSet = [
"https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5475/9790841974_182a06590a_o.jpg",
"https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2840/9042399407_bf04388aca_o.jpg",
"https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5504/14634417581_626ea1a835_o.jpg"
];

var p = photoSet.length;
console.log(p);
var i = 1;

function loopPhotos() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $('div').css({'background-image': 'url(' + photoSet[i] + ')',});
    i++;
    console.log(i);

// call the next indexed image and begin to preload it

var img = new Image();
img.src = photoSet[i];

if (i >= p) {
        i = 0;      

  // stop preloading images, somehow used images that are cached so the browser isn't working eternally reloading the same X number of photos.

    }

loopPhotos();

}, 2000)
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // load first image

  var firstImg = new Image();
  firstImg.src = photoSet[0];

  // when first image is loaded, apply it to background and begin looping

  if (firstImg.complete) {
$('div').css({'background-image': 'url(' + firstImg.src + ')',});
loopPhotos();
console.log('first image loaded!');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
var photoSet = [
  "https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5475/9790841974_182a06590a_o.jpg",
  "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2840/9042399407_bf04388aca_o.jpg",
  "https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5504/14634417581_626ea1a835_o.jpg"
];

function preloadImageAndAct(src, action){
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = action;
  img.src = src;
}

function showImage( src ){
  $('div').css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + src + ')',
    opacity: 1
  });
}

var nextImage = 0;

function loopPhotos() {
  console.log('Preload and show image #', nextImage);
  var nextSrc = photoSet[nextImage];
  preloadImageAndAct( nextSrc, function(){
    showImage( nextSrc );
    setTimeout( function() {
      nextImage++;
      nextImage %= photoSet.length;
      loopPhotos();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  loopPhotos();
});
```

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/rarPay

---

Keep in mind that you cannot transition the `background-image`. If you want transition for the change of images you need to either use two elements or fade the element out / change `src` / fade the element in.

AS for the caching, once they have been loaded once they are automatically cached by the browser so there should be no issue with that.